# Error to start new Activity with Intent after click Button in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick

I try to start `Place.Class` which show more Detail of each place.

Following here I Have `AboutMap` extends `MapActivity`. I aslo create AlertDialog with Button `See more detail` here. But it's not work..When i run program, it crashes after Click  `See more detail` Button. And i didn't get the exactly the result that it should be.. I think it must be wrong somewhere.. may be here

`Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Place.class);` //But i don't know how to fix it

Do you guys have any idea?  Thanks you so much for your help

`PlaceItemizedOverlay`

```
    public class PlaceItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

        private Context mContext;

        private Cursor c;

        private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

        public PlaceItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
        {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
            mContext = context;

        }
        public PlaceItemizedOverlay(Context context)
        {
            super(boundCenterBottom(null));
            mContext = context;

        }
        public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
            mOverlays.add(overlay);
            populate();
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return mOverlays.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return mOverlays.size();    }


        @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {

    //Create AlertDialog
          final OverlayItem oi = mOverlays.get(index);
          AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
          dialog.setTitle(oi.getTitle());
          dialog.setMessage(oi.getSnippet());
          dialog.setNegativeButton("Back", null);
  //Create See more detail Button
          dialog.setPositiveButton("See More Detail", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Line 87: Logcat tell that there are some problem around here
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Place.class); 
                    i.putExtra(Constants.KEY_ID, c.getInt(
                            c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID)));
                    i.putExtra(Constants.COL_TITLE, c.getString(
                            c.getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_TITLE)));
                    i.putExtra(Constants.COL_ADDRESS, c.getString(
                            c.getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_ADDRESS)));
                    i.putExtra(Constants.COL_CONTENT, c.getString(
                            c.getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_CONTENT)));
                    mContext.startActivity(i);
            }});
          dialog.show();
          return true;

        }


    }
```

---

`AboutMap.class`

```
public class AboutMap extends MapActivity {

    MapView mapView;
    MapController mapController;
    private static MyDB mDbHelper;
    private Cursor c;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aboutcm);

        mDbHelper = new MyDB(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();
        mDbHelper.open();
        c = mDbHelper.getAttraction();



        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin_3);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        PlaceItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new PlaceItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        mapController.setZoom(13); 
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        c.moveToFirst(); 
        do {
            String title = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_TITLE));
            String address = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_ADDRESS));
            int latitude = (int) (c.getDouble(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_LA)) * 1E6);
            int longitude = (int) (c.getDouble(c
                    .getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_LONG)) * 1E6);

            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), title,
                    address));

            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);


        } while (c.moveToNext());


    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }



}
```

---

`Logcat`

```
09-04 14:31:29.019: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(975): Shutting down VM
09-04 14:31:29.029: WARN/dalvikvm(975): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
09-04 14:31:29.029: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at com.ctg.PlaceItemizedOverlay$1.onClick(PlaceItemizedOverlay.java:87)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
09-04 14:31:29.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(975):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 14:31:29.099: INFO/Process(53): Sending signal. PID: 975 SIG: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `Cursor c` is null. In your `PlaceItemizedOverlay` I see you have declared a private variable `c` but you have not assigned to it anywhere. The `onClick` code refers to this variable and will crash as above.

I guess you want to pass your Cursor in from your `AboutMap` Activity. Maybe add another parameter to the constructor of `PlaceItemizedOverlay` to share the cursor?

```
public PlaceItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context, Cursor cursor)
        {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
            mContext = context;
            c = cursor;

        }
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. i got it. Thanks you so much. The last thing i would like to ask u..is that, when i click `See more detail button`,but, Every places pop up at once. this is weird. I wanna it show only 1 place per one click and the same title, same information.

I think it might because of mContext. But, i have no idea how to fix this. Do you have any idea? Anyway, Thanks you so much for your kindness

Comment: I guess this depends on your implementation of the Place activity? You would have to show the code for that for anyone to see what is going wrong. Maybe you could create a new question (as opposed to in this comment stream) and describe it fully too, so there is more chance for people to see it and help you. :)

Comment: I got got it now...How stupid am i? LOL anyway, thank you so much